# Calculate with agregates and save on table field on django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

How to calculate the total of invoice using sum annotate or agregate instead of forloop and save the value on field invoice.total

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    client = models.ForeignKey('Client',on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    total = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)

    def totalsubtotals(self):
        items = self.invoiceitem_set.all()
        total = 0
        for item in items:
            total += item.subtotal
        return total

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.total = self.totalsubtotals()
        super(Invoice, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class InvoiceItem(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey('Invoice', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    subtotal = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.subtotal = self.price * self.quantity
        super(InvoiceItem, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Please *don't*. This is a form of data duplication. If you later change the price of an `InvoiceItem`, then the `total` will no longer be in sync, or when you add/remove an `InvoiceItem`. Calculate the total through annotation.

Answer (score 3):

Please **don't**. This is a form of *data duplication*: you store some part of the data twice: both the `subtotal`s and the `total`. In fact `subtotal` is not necessary either.

It turns out that keeping data in sync is a hard problem. Imagine that you later change the quantity of an `InvoiceItem`, then you will not save the `Invoice` again, and thus the total is no longer correct. If you remove an `InvoiceItem` or you create a new `InvoiceItem`, then that is not the case either. You can make use of signals, but a lot of Django ORM calls will *not* run the signals. Indeed for example:

```
from django.db.models import F

InvoiceItem.objects.filter(pk=14).update(quantity=F('quantity')+1)
```

Here we thus increment a `quantity`, but the `subtotal` and `total` will *not* be updated, not even if we use signals.

You can try to implement this at the *database level* through triggers, but that will require manually adding triggers, and it is furthermore still likely you forget a scenario then eventually the data will get out of sync.

It is therefore more convenient *not* to use duplicated data. You can for example calculate the `subtotal` through a property:

```
class InvoiceItem(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey('Invoice', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    
    @property
    def subtotal(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity
```

for the `Invoice` you should not calculate this at the Django/Pyton layer, since that will take too much time and result in extra querying. You can use [**`.annotate(…)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) in the views where you need the total of the `Invoice`s with:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

Invoice.objects.annotate(
    total=Sum(F('invoiceitem__quantity') * F('price'))
)
```

Your `Invoice` model thus does not contain a `total` or any subroutines to recalculate the total:

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    client = models.ForeignKey('Client',on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Comment: as it s for an invoicing app, so it s the opposite, if i create an invoiceitem today and next month i change the price, so old invoiceitems and invoices totals will change too. so then it will be too complicated to control it. but this way, i think storing whole things will be much efficient and also for using filters will be easier

Comment: @youssefmohamed: but the `invoiceitem` simply copies the price from the product I assume? To make matters even worse, if you add items, you *first* create the `Invoice`, and *then* you add `Invoice`s, so the `.save()` method will not "fire" when you add elements.

Comment: @youssefmohamed: the idea is that you should save *historical* prices of a product, such that it is easy to recalculate these. This makes the data "stateless", in the sense that if you later would have to "correct" an order where someone bought an item at a certain point in time, it is easy to do that. By copying data, you simply make it "untracable" how you obtained that price. If you thus make a "historical price" model, you can simply create an invoice for any given point in time.

Comment: @youssefmohamed: signals are antipatterns (https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/). You are here making a "stateful" application, which makes it unstable. You should simply define modeling such that you can reconstruct the price of products at any point in time. So you can find out what the price was of a product three years ago.

Comment: complicated in my case to do historical prices. then you recommand me to keep it with method and don t save it or annotate on views ?

Comment: @youssefmohamed: but I assume that if you create an `InvoiceItem`, you will copy the price from the product to the `InvoiceItem`, so even if you later change the `price` of that product, it does not matter, since all the annotates only work on the price stored in the *`InvoiceItem`* model.

Comment: yes just did it with a js script so i can get the price automatically when i choose product in invoiceitem. can you do me a method as asked before for totalsubtotals so i can apply it for a different field but same concept. thx